# Translating code to numpy for better performance

Tags: python, numpy, scientific-computing

I have this:

```
partial = {}
for d in devs["d"]:
    for k in a1km:
        total = len(cp[(cp["r"]==d) & (cp["s"]==k)])
        partial.update({str(d)+str(k): total})
```

Variables `cp` and `devs` are `pandas` dataframes, and `a1km` is a dictionary that contains a site, and all sites 1km from it (pre calculated). The output I'm after would be, for each `d` and for each site `k`, all the records in the `cp` dataframe that matches the query, stored `total`, so:

```
d, k, total
```

I've never worked with `numpy`, and I'm trying to learn as fast as I can, but the library is just too big for me to process, given time considerations in my lab. So my question is, how do I "translate" the code below to `numpy` to imporve performance?

Comment: Please share a sample of the data and the expected output

Comment: Also please clarify... What is `devs`, what is `cp`, what is `a1km`...?

Comment: @yatu: thanks for the suggestions, I've edited the question.

Comment: Still not useful... Please share an example dataframe and dictionary so we can reproduce your code

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the dataframe and use [pandas.DataFrame.groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```py
tmp = cp[(cp['r'].isin(devs['d'].unique()) & (cp['s'].isin(a1km))]

result_df = tmp.groupby(['r','s']).size()
```

Remark that this can be quite slow as well.

Then to make it into a dictionary:

```py
partial = {str(k[0]) + str(k[1]): v for k,v in result_df.to_dict().items()}
```